# Spring Boot with Legacy tables

Tags: spring-boot

I want to use Spring Boot with Legacy database and use hibernate for the same. I have to access both DB2 and Teradata as data sources.I would like to know if this is possible ? I'm a newbie to Spring , SpringBoot and have no idea how to configure data sources , should i still need multiple xml configs etc. The demos in spring io sites are good but they dont deal with any of my requirement. Kindly point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot it is very easy to configure multiple datasources. [This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) part of the documentation describes the procedure in detail.

In essence, all you need to do is have the connection properties in a place where Spring boot can locate them (the easiest place is `application.properties`) and then configure the beans. The code would look like:

**application.properties**

```
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
datasource.primary.username=dbuser
datasource.primary.password=dbpass

datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test2
datasource.secondary.username=dbuser2
datasource.secondary.password=dbpass2
```

**Spring configuration file**

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

You will notice that no XML configuration is used which the preferred style these days. Actually using Spring Boot means that you don't have to write almost any configuration :)